# UISwitch within UIScrollview nearly impossible to use

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm using a UISwitch-Component at the bottom of a view that sits within a UIScrollView.
Now the problem that appeared, is that the switch is nearly impossible to swipe because the UIScrollView seems to dominate the userinput.

Switching works very well by tapping the switch, but from my point of view, most users "switch" the UISwitch instead of tapping.

Did anyone of you face the same / or similar problems and managed to come up with a solution?

thx in advance

sam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a design decision to make: if your content is meant to scroll horizontally, then a user swipe over a switch is ambiguous -- does it mean they want to scroll, or toggle the switch?

The easiest solution is to modify your UI so that this ambiguity disappears.  For example, if the scroll's `contentSize` is not wider than the bounds of the scroll view, then it can't scroll horizontally, and a horizontal swipe will always activate the switch.

If you do want to allow horizontal scrolling, then it makes sense to replace the `UISwitch` with a `UIButton` that toggles on touch, similar to a play/pause button.

On the other hand, if you don't want to modify your UI, you could always just do:

```
myScrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
```

This will cause your switch to "get" the touches immediately, rather than have them go to the `UIScrollView` first.  [More info here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/delaysContentTouches).  (You can also set this boolean in Interface Builder, as pointed out by Squeegy.)

Comment: Hey Tyler. Thx for your reply, setting the delaysContentTouches to NO solved my Issue. My Scrollview is only vertically scrollable so i think its not a design issue.. thx!