# UISwitch value change event is not triggered iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiswitch

I am adding the UISwitch programmatically in a scroll view.

**UIVIew -> UIScrollView -> UISwitch**

```
UISwitch *toggleSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectZero];
[toggleSwitch addTarget:self action:@selector(flipMode:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
toggleSwitch.on = YES;
toggleSwitch.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[scrollView addSubview: toggleSwitch];
```

**Action method:**

```
- (IBAction)flipMode:(id)sender{    
    if([sender isOn])
    {
       // On Toggle ON
    } else {
     //On Toggle OFF
    }
}
```

When we toggle the switch multiple times or on dragging or moving the switch slowly from ON to OFF state or vice versa at some point of time the action is not getting called. In next moment on value change it will trigger the event.

Occurrence of this issue is 2 out of 15-20 trials. Unable to find the root cause for it.

Help appreciated

Comment: are you implementing `[switchName setOn:YES animated:YES];`

Comment: Yes, the default value is there..

Comment: paste code of 'flipMode' method

Comment: try using `void` instead of `IBAction` in method return type

Comment: Occurrence is 2 out of 15. is occurrence for working or not working?

Comment: check my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

set your `delaysContentTouches` property of scroll view to NO

```
yourScrollView.delaysContentTouches = NO;
```

> This will cause your switch to "get" the touches immediately, rather
>   than have them go to the UIScrollView first.
>   Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2547146/3976183) answer.

your `flipMethod:` should look like below code

```
-(void)flipMode:(id)sender
{
 if([sender isOn])
   [toggleSwitch setOn:YES animated:YES];
 else
   [toggleSwitch setOn:NO animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: I made the changes but still the same issue is occurred.

Comment: may be problem due to `UISwitch` in scroll view

Comment: I figured out a workaround for it, on slowly dragging the switch the action was getting called multiple times. referred this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19628310/ios7-uiswitch-its-event-valuechanged-calling-continuously-is-this-bug-or-what